# Set the backgroundView of MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, email, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I would like to set the backgroundView of the MFMailComposerViewController tableView. However I have been trying everything for about 30mins or so. I have managed to add the backgroundView as a subview to the MFMailComposerViewController's view, but that covers the whole screen. Does anyone know how I could accomplish setting the backgroundView of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your app to be accepted in the app store, don't. It will probably get your app rejected. [The documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) specifically states

> The mail composition interface itself is not customizable and must not be modified by your application.

If you're not intending to submit your app to the app store, you'd have to dig around in the subviews (and possibly sub-subviews, etc.) of the controller and see if you can find the right one to manipulate the background on.